# Не получается написать в файл русскими буквами

Tags: python

Проблема вот в чем, мне нужно создать файл, и в нем написать русские слова! Но почему-то в конце концов у меня в файле, который я создал появляются только квадратики и все. Я проверял, если сделать английские буквы то все работает. В чем может быть проблема? Кодировка `UTF-8`, `Python3.2`.

Comment: А поподробнее можно? А то под это описание попадает столько разных вариантов, что мама, не горюй.

Comment: А пишешь юникод-строки? Т.е. u"Какая-то строка"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите кодировку той программы, в которой вы редактируете файлы. Например, если вы редактируете файлы через `PuTTY`, в настройках сессии необходимо выставить кодировку `UTF-8`, иначе, как и у вас, будут квадратики печататься, вместо русских букв.

Comment: Я поставил так, чтобы у меня автоматически сохранялось всё в utf-8

Comment: Надо не только сохранять в utf-8, но и чтобы utf-8 правильно отображалась, чтоб с буфером обмена ваш редактор корректно работал.

Answer (score 0):

В начале файла напишите:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

Comment: неа не помогло! я могу вывести на экран при помощи print русские буквы а вот именно в файлик.тхт не могу получаются квадратики!у меня akelPad сам автоматом в utf-8 сохраняет